# Proving the formula of the geometric sum through induction

Tags: summation, induction, closed-form

How do I go about proving $\sum \limits _{j=0} ^{n-1} q^j = \tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}$ inductively? I can't seem to work with $n-1$.

So far, I have $\tfrac{1 - q^{n-1}} {1-q}+q^n$ = $\tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}$

$\tfrac{1 - q^{n-1}+q^n-q^{n+1}} {1-q}$ = $\tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}$

I can't simplify the numerator on the left side.

Is this correct?:
$-q^{n+1}-q^{n-1}$ = $-2q^n$?

Then I will have: $1-2q^n$+$q^n$=$1-q^n$

Comment: you made a mistake in the line which begins by so far..  $+q^n$ must be replaced by $q^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because
you don't want to show this:

$\tfrac{1 - q^{n-1}} {1-q}+q^n
=\tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}
$.

You want to show this:

$\tfrac{1 - q^{n-1}} {1-q}+q^{n-1}
=\tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}
$.

The exponent of $q$
in the fraction
is one more
than the exponent
in the last term
in the sum.

So if the sum goes up to
$q^k$,
the numerator of the fraction
is
$1-q^{k+1}
$.

---

Here is a more explicit explanation.

You want to show that
$\sum \limits _{j=0} ^{n-1} q^j = \tfrac {1 - q^n} {1-q}
$.

Putting $n+1$ for $n$,
this is
$\sum \limits _{j=0} ^{n} q^j = \tfrac {1 - q^{n+1}} {1-q}
$.

The difference of the
two left hand sides is
$\sum \limits _{j=0} ^{n} q^j-\sum \limits _{j=0} ^{n-1} q^j
=q^n
$.

The difference of
the two right hand sides is

$\begin{array}\\
\tfrac {1 - q^{n+1}} {1-q}-\tfrac {1 - q^{n}} {1-q}
&=\tfrac {(1 - q^{n+1})-(1 - q^{n})} {1-q}\\
&=\tfrac {q^n - q^{n+1}} {1-q}\\
&=\tfrac {q^n(1 - q)} {1-q}\\
&= q^n\\
\end{array}
$

Since the two sides agree
for $n=1$,
and their differences are the same
(both $q^n$)
when you go from
$n$ to $n+1$,
the two sides are
always the same.

This is a frequently useful
method of proof by induction:

To show that
$s(n) = t(n)$
for all $n$,
show that
$s(1) = t(1)$
and
$s(n+1)-s(n)
= t(n+1)-t(n)
$.

Comment: So I substitute n-1 for $q^n$, why do I not do the same for $q^n$?

Comment: I added some additional explanation.