# Prove the following summation-implication

Tags: summation, proof-writing

Can someone please show me to to prove this summation-implication?

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z^+}, x \neq 1 \implies \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right) $$

Note: This is cleary a different one from [Proving the geometric sum formula by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction) so please stop down-voting.

Comment: Why don't you try induction on $n$? The base case is easy to check, and the inductive case is just addition of polynomials.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I don't see how that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945393/proving-the-formula-of-the-geometric-sum-through-induction.

Comment: @YahyaFarooq Can you at least see the base case? Take $n=1$, then the left hand side is $\sum_{i=0}^0 x^i = x^0=1$ while the right hand side is just $\frac{x-1}{x-1} = 1$. Similarly, assume the result for $n=k$ and prove it for $n=k+1$. All you need to do is to add $x^{k+1}$ to both sides then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the geometric sum formula by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction)

Comment: You have asked 4 questions in 3 hours. Don't you think you should slow down and take time to work by yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

Using identity $$x^n-y^n = (x-y)\cdot (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x^i\cdot y^{n-1-i})$$
Putting y=1 $$\implies x^n-1 = (x-1)\cdot (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i
\implies \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$
Hence proved.